# Есть ли у каждой открывающей скобки закрывающая?

Tags: java

Есть 3 строки вида

```
(()) ))(( (()))
```

Задача: выдать, имеет ли каждая открывающая скобочка соответствующую закрывающуюся:

```
( - false () - true ()) - false )( - false (())() - true
```

Мое решение:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "(())";
        String str2 = "))((";
        String str3 = "(()))";

 System.out.println("String (())");
 System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {

        if ((str1.charAt(i) == '(')&& (str1.indexOf(')') > str1.indexOf('('))) {
            System.out.println("str1.charAt("+ i+ ")" + str1.charAt(i) + " true ");
        } else {System.out.println("str1.charAt("+ i+ ")" + str1.charAt(i)
                    + " false ");
        }}
  System.out.println("String ))((");
  System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++) {

        if ((str2.charAt(i) == '(')&& (str2.indexOf(')') > str2.indexOf('('))) {
            System.out.println("str1.charAt("+ i+ ")" + str1.charAt(i) + " true ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("str1.charAt("+ i+ ")" + str2.charAt(i)+ " false ");
        }}

    System.out.println("String (()))");
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < str3.length(); i++) {

        if ((str3.charAt(i) == '(')&& (str3.indexOf(')') > str3.indexOf('('))) {
            System.out.println("str1.charAt("+ i+ ")" + str1.charAt(i) + " true
");
        } else {
            System.out.println("str1.charAt("+ i+ ")" + str3.charAt(i)+ " false ");
        }}}}
```

Ответ соответственно:

```
String (())

str1.charAt(0)( true 
str1.charAt(1)( true 
str1.charAt(2)) false 
str1.charAt(3)) false 
String ))((

str1.charAt(0)) false 
str1.charAt(1)) false 
str1.charAt(2)( false 
str1.charAt(3)( false 
String (()))

str1.charAt(0)( true 
str1.charAt(1)( true 
str1.charAt(2)) false 
str1.charAt(3)) false 
str1.charAt(4)) false
```

Мой вопрос: как сделать так, чтоб ответ был

```
( - false () - true ()) - false
```

Comment: Вы тут что-то странное и неверное понаворотили. Почему бы вам просто не использовать `stack` для проверки парности скобок?

Comment: int i=0;

Если программа натыкается на открывающую скобку, ++i;

Если прога увидела зкрывающуюу --i;

Если в конце результат !(i==0) значит плохи дела

Comment: @argamidon, это не будет работать. Например, ")(" выдаст в результате ноль. Это лишь проверка на равенство количества открывающих и закрывающих скобок.

Comment: Ну да. :-(

Comment: Написал точно такое же решение без учета наличия открывающей скобки, а ведь два дня назад делал идентичное тестовое, блин.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class Application {
    private static final char OPENING_PARENTHESIS = '(';
    private static final char CLOSING_PARENTHESIS = ')';

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String str1 = "(())";
        final String str2 = "))((";
        final String str3 = "(()))";

        System.out.println(checkParentheses(str1));
        System.out.println(checkParentheses(str2));
        System.out.println(checkParentheses(str3));
    }

    private static boolean checkParentheses(CharSequence line) {
        final Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();

        for (int i = 0, length = line.length(); i < length; ++i) {
            final char ch = line.charAt(i);

            if (ch == OPENING_PARENTHESIS) {
                stack.add(OPENING_PARENTHESIS);
            } else if (ch == CLOSING_PARENTHESIS) {
                if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                    return false;
                }
                stack.pop();
            }
        }

        return stack.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Comment: ЫЫыы какой ещё стак он почти deprecated, лучше какой нибудь LinkedList c его интерфейсоМ Deque.

Comment: @argamidon, не выдумывайте насчёт `deprecated`. В [документации][1] об этом ни слова. И не думаю, что имеет значение, что использовать в тестовом примере.

  [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Comment: `stack.peek() == OPENING_PARENTHESIS` — а что там ещё может быть? С другой стороны, мне нравится использование констант и выделение методов.

Comment: @Im ieee, да, вы правы, удалил ненужное условие.

Comment: @falstaf, осталось ещё совсем избавиться от стека, ну и получить по смыслу моё решение. Кстати, по вашей ссылке: A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class.

Comment: @Im ieee, да там все решения без полноценного парсинга по смыслу одинаковые.

Comment: @Im ieee, `Stack` рекомендуется не использовать прежде всего из-за его внутренней структуры (он основывается на `Vector`'е), а так же из-за отсутствия выделяемого интерфейса, то есть возможности заменить имплементацию. Что из этого вы действительно считаете важным для десятистрочного тестового примера?

Comment: @Etki а какой в данной задаче может быть «полноценный парсинг»? И решения вообще-то могут отличаться хотя бы по объему занимаемой памяти. А если `Stack` основан на `Vector`, то и по производительности.  
@falstaf Мне кажется, хороший тон в программировании — использовать предпочтительные классы.

Comment: @Im ieee токенизация и последующее построение дерева выражений. Какая, впрочем, разница?

> хотя бы по объему занимаемой памяти. А если Stack основан на Vector, то и по производительности.

О господи

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String[] args2={"()()", ")()(", "((", "))", "(()())", ")("};
        for(String arg: args2){
            int cnt=0, i;
            for(i=0; i<arg.length(); i++){
                if(arg.charAt(i)=='('){
                    cnt++;
                } else if(arg.charAt(i)==')'){
                    if(cnt==0){
                        break;
                    }
                    cnt--;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(cnt==0 && i==arg.length());
        }
    }
```

[IDEOne](https://ideone.com/YgcgwN)

Почему-то IDEOne не читает аргументы из stdin.